# Formato JSON errado web api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Estou tendo problema ao retornar json na minha api mvc 5.

No metodo Get ele retorna uma string neste formato:

```
public string Get()
        {
           return "{\"data\":[{\"Codigo\":\"AAAA\",\"Finalidade\":\"AAAA\"},{\"Codigo\":\"AAAA\",\"Finalidade\":\"AAAA\"}]}"
}
```

Quando solicito na minha pagina `localhost:9640/api/apiimovel?formato=json` 
olha o formato:

```
"{\"data\":[{\"Codigo\":\"AAAA\",\"Finalidade\":\"AAAA\"},{\"Codigo\":\"AAAA\",\"Finalidade\":\"AAAA\"}]}"
```

Mas quando eu faço essa consulta pelo controller normal o json retorna correto !!

O que ocorre este problema ?

Comment: Quer dizer que quando acessa `localhost:9640/api/apiimovel?formato=json`, as barras vêm na string? Em C# você manda `"aa\"bb"`, e do outro lado, em vez de receber `aa"bb`, você está recebendo `aa\"bb`?

Comment: Acredito que você não entendeu muito bem o conceito de web.api. Leia esse link que pode lhe ajudar muito: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 2):

A finalidade do webapi é que você retorna o resultado fortemente tipado e a API se encarrega de dar o parse para o formato JSON (ou XML). Do modo que você está fazendo está sendo retornado um JSON de uma string e não o json do seu objeto.

Crie uma classe com as propriedades Código e Finalidade, preencha o array instanciado com os seus dados, e retorne da função:

API:

```
public Lista Get() {
    var result = new Lista {
        data = new[] {
            new Item {Codigo = "AAA", Finalidade = "AAAAAAA"},
            new Item {Codigo = "AAA", Finalidade = "AAAAAAA"}
        }
    };

    return result;
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Lista {
    public Item[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Finalidade { get; set; }
}
```